# Neo4J Desktop 1.1.8 Installation Error (Community Edition)

Tags: neo4j, failed-installation

For Neo4J Desktop 1.1.8 (Community Edition), I get an installation error when I install for just my user (since I don't have admin permissions).

The actual installation seems to go OK, but when the Neo4J Desktop appears, I get an error:

> Initialization error: Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, open '\Neo4j\distributions\java\zulu8.21.0.1-jdk8.0.131\ASSEMBLY_EXCEPTION'.